# Should I learn C# or Java first?

Tags: c#, java

What is your advice? Should I learn Java or C# first? I know only PHP.

I would like to write desktop apps for Windows.

Thank you.

P.S. I noticed that C# tag has here on stackoverflow 200 000 times usage and java only 150 000. Does this fact mean that Java is not so widely used as is C#?

Comment: this might be a question better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: The majority of Stack Overflow's community is using a Microsoft stack, true, but that doesn't mean that Java is worse. Anyway, for what it's worth, I'd suggest C# because it has compiler support for true OOP constructs whereas Java is kind of like an Alzheimer patient (yes, generics, I'm looking at you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows desktop apps: Probably C# is the choice.